# PEAR2 - Mbox not installing correctly

Tags: php, pear, mbox, pyrus

Im attempting to install the Mail_Mbox-0.6.3 package as i need to use the classes for accessing email attachments from php.

However when i try to install using the newpackage manager it keeps giving me errors.

```
php pyrus.phar install pear/Mail_Mbox-0.6.3
```

Returns the following

```
Using PEAR installation found at pear2
Downloading pear.php.net/Mail_Mbox

Connected...

PEAR2\Pyrus\Package\Exception: Invalid abstract package pear.php.net/Mail_Mbox
PEAR2\Pyrus\HTTPException: Download of http://pear.php.net/get/Mail_Mbox-0.6.3.phar failed, file does not exist
PEAR2\Pyrus\Package\Exception: Could not download from "http://pear.php.net/get/Mail_Mbox-0.6.3.tgz"
PEAR2\Pyrus\Package\Exception: Unable to save package Mail_Mbox-0.6.3.tgz to downloads directory, pear2/downloads. Do we have permission to write there?
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```
$ php pyrus.phar install pear/mail_mbox-alpha
Pyrus version 2.0.0a4 SHA-1: 72271D92C3AA1FA96DF9606CD538868544609A52
Using PEAR installation found at /home/christian.weiske/php/phpfarm/inst/php-5.3.3/pear
Downloading pear.php.net/Mail_Mbox
Mime-type: application/octet-stream
Installed pear.php.net/Mail_Mbox-0.6.3
```